.NET 8, EF Core query could not be translated when using a static collection/list as field
I'm curious about the following:

Why is EF Core unable to translate a static readonly ICollection<T> & static readonly IList<T> field into a query when using it inside of a .Contains()? When removing the static keyword it seems to execute the query just fine?
When using IEnumerable<T> This is not an issue, is this because of the different .Contains() that's being used?
This is only happening when the List/Collection are static, why is that so important here for the query to be translated?

I got this from the exception: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval but that doesn't really explain to me why this is happening only when using a static collection.
Let's say I have this database model when using EF Core:
public class Item
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}

And in my class I have the following field (this can be a static readonly IList<T> or static readonly ICollection<T>):
private static readonly IList<string> AllowedFooCodes = new List<string>() { "ABC", "CED" };

My db class looks something like this:
public class SampleDataRepository : ISampleDataRepository
{
    private readonly ILogger<SampleDataRepository> _logger;
    private readonly SampleDataStore _sampleDataStore;

    // Can be IList or ICollection, exception will be thrown regardless.
    private static readonly IList<string> AllowedFooCodes = new List<string>() { "ABC", "CED" };
    
    public SampleDataRepository(SampleDataStore store, ILogger<SampleDataRepository> logger)
    {
        _sampleDataStore = store;
        _logger = logger;
    }
    
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Item>> GetItems()
    {
        _sampleDataStore.Items
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .Where(item => AllowedFooCodes.Contains(item.foo))
                        .ToListAsync();
    }
}

I'm looking forward to your answers.

If adding var allowedFooCodes = AllowedFooCodes; and using the local variable in your query works, then this is probably a bug.  Use that as a workaround and post an issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues

Also try convert field to static property. Anyway, looks like a bug or limitation.

I changed the field to a private static property, this seems to be a workaround, using a local variable seems to work as well.

Probably because when using a non-static field/variable, it forces the variable (or this) to be captured into the lambda expression as a parameter, whereas with a static variable, it comes through the expression tree directly. I agree this is a bug and should be reported.

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/35024 I raised an issue for this.

Does seem like a bit of a bug, I have used code like that and don't recall issues, but I used a static readonly IEnumerable<T> Typically an arrangement of common constant values like that should be immutable so it's a bit odd to expose as IList or ICollection as that implies any consumer could add to it? Curiously if you remove readonly it works as well. Seems some kind of optimization or allowance in Linq for static readonly collections isn't translatable in EF. If the set of values cannot be altered at runtime then I suggest static readonly IEnumerable<string>

Seems like it was indeed a bug, looks like a Pull Request is already out for it as well: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/pull/35029
